# Rails 5: jQuery autocomplete json not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement a `JQuery-ui` autocomplete on a search `form_tag`. I have followed [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/399-autocomplete-search-terms?view=asciicast) in order to implement it.

This is what I have done thus far but without the desired results:

- Installed the `Jquery-ui` manually and thus 0 errors show in the
  browser source inspector.
- I have added the `jQuery` code for autocompletion.
- I have generated the `search_suggestion` resource.

And added the following to the `search_suggestion_controller.rb` in order to test if the `json` is rendered:

```
class SearchSuggestionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: %w[foo bar]
  end
end
```

But absolutely nothing renders/shows as it is supposed to do!

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Here is my other code:

```
<%= form_tag items_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Enter keyword to search', class: "search-query search_size" %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search', style: "display: none;" %>
<% end %>
```

items_controller.rb

```
def search
  if params[:search]
    @items = Item.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @items.map(&:title) }
    end
  else
    @items = []
  end
end
```

item.rb

```
def self.search(term)
  return where("0=1") if term !~ /\w{4}/
  where("lower(title) LIKE lower(:term)", term: "%#{term}%")
end
```

items.coffee

```
jQuery ->
$('#search').autocomplete
 source: "/search_suggestions"
```

Comment: Do you get valid JSON when you navigate to `/search_suggestions` in your web browser?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Daniel Westendorf... Yes I do get`["foo","bar"]`, but its not showing on the searchbox as its suppose to.

Comment: Hey - couple of questions here:

+ Does the element definitely have the id `#search` when it's rendered on the page?
+ Have you put in any debug points to confirm that a) the autocomplete hits the controller and b) it gets the json back in the response (you can use the [response listener](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete#event-response) for this)?